# Express/Node.js post endpoint shows [object Object] instead of Array of Objects

Tags: node.js, angular, express, http

I use Angular on the frontend and send a post request to a backend built with Express.

This is how the Angular code looks:

```
  addEntry() {
    let type = "Random Type";
    let location = "Random Location";
    let date = new Date();
    let results = [
      { name: "my first name", age: 23 },
      { name: "new second name", age: 35 },
    ];

    return this.http.post<{ message: string }>(
      this._url + "/myendpoint/add",
      { type, location, date, results }
    );
  }
```

And this is how the express code looks like:

```
router.post(
  "/add",
  middleware.verifyToken,
  async function (req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json(errors.array());
    }

    try {
      let userID = req.tokenData.userID;
      let user = await User.findOne({ _id: userID });
      if (user === null || user.length <= 0) {
        return res.status(422).json("Could not add entry");
      } else {
        let type = req.body.type;
        let location = req.body.location;
        let date = req.body.date;

        console.log(req.body);

        let results = req.body.results.map(async (el) => {
          let result = await Entry.findOne({ name: el.name });
          return {
            name: result.name,
            age: el.age,
          };
        });

        [some more code ...]

      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(422).json(err);
    }
  }
);
```

The console log outputs:

```
{
  type: 'Random Type',
  centre: 'Random Location',
  date: '2020-06-19T16:50:25.357Z',
  results: '[object Object]'
}
```

And I also receive this error which is probably generated because the results show as '[object Object]';

```
TypeError: req.body.results.map is not a function
```

How do I get the results array in Express instead of '[object Object]'? I have the following settings enabled in Express:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: How you tried stringifying your POST body? `JSON.stringify({ type, location, date, results })`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help... it still didn't work on its own... very strange behaviour. I've tried to combine it with JSON parse, encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent though and it seems to work.

Comment: You shouldn't need to encode the stringifyied JSON, as you're not sending it in the URI/URL. But you may need to set the `Content-Type` header in you `http` request to `application/json`. The `Content-Type` header will tell Express how to handle the data in the body.

Comment: I set the content-type header to application/json, but Angular escapes the JSON.stringify() and what I receive in the backend is something that contains lots of &quot;

Comment: If you don't stringify the JSON body, but do put the `application/json` `Content-Type` header, what type is the request body (`typeof(req.body)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular: results: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(results));

In Express: JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(req.body.results));

Answer (score 0):

I have less reputation so i cant post a comment, have you tried results[1]['name']; ?

Comment: It should be like, results[1]['name'];

Comment: I tried... still "undefined". For some reason it doesn't recognise the array as the map function doesn't work either, it says "req.body.results.map is not a function".